# Wordpress : Prevent from serving webp images on button-based download

Tags: wordpress, download, png, webp

The `png` and `jpg` images of my Wordpress site are programatically converted into `webp` formats thanks to an extension (I've tried different, including *WebP Converter for Media* and *WebP Express*).

There are pages that display an image. I would like to add a button that enable users to download the image. I'm currently using the following code :

```
<a href="path/to/my/img.png" download="img">
   <button type="button"> Download </button>
</a>
```

Nevertheless, upon hit, the image to be download corresponds to its `webp` version - not the `png` as encoded in the image path.

I would like to know :

- Is it possible to force the server to serve the `png` image upon button click, either with a client side information (included in the image path, or in the ?) or  with a server side condition (if page==X and request==Y, return png)?
- (Worse but possible) Is it possible to prevent the server from converting `png` to `webp`, either by excluding some pages in a given extension, or by adding some `php` functions directly in the code ?

Otherwise, what other strategies have I missed to have `webp` images rendered but the ability to easily save as `png`?

Note: Chrome works as expected : png instead of webp image upon download, and, webp image upon `save as` on image directly. Firefox though download images as webp wether it is on the image or through the download button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't find a definitive general answer, but apparently, the *WebP Express* plugin [skips URLs that contain a query string](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/prevent-webp-images-on-certain-templates-or-pages-2/).

Therefore, if you `?original` to the image URL in the  link, you would "force" the serve not to encode your original png image into a webp format.

This just writes :

```
<a href="path/to/my/img.png?original" download="img">
   <button type="button"> Download </button>
</a>
```

Note : I don't know whether this works with other plugins.